# JavaScript method that can add some character at the begining and end of another string

Tags: javascript, jquery, lodash

I have been using join() which "Join the elements of an array into a string".

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
 var energy = fruits.join();
```

**results in** `Banana,Orange,Apple,Mango`

Do we have a method which can result in something like this

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
     var energy = fruits.New_Method('{','}');
```

should result in

```
{Banana}  {Orange} {Apple} {Mango}
```

I can do this with the help of for loop but I want to know if there is any inbuilt method which can do this for me.

Comment: `var energy = '{' + fruits.join('} {') + '}';`?

Comment: There is no in-build method for standard-javascript.

Comment: @putvande I'd upvote that answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just do:

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var energy = '{' + fruits.join('} {') + '}';
```

Answer (score 1):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tLH7S/1/)

```
var energy = '{';
energy += fruits.join('} {');
energy += '}';
alert("Energy : " + energy);
```

You could get alert as

```
Energy : {Banana} {Orange} {Apple} {Mango}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's also a functional way, resembling more what you *want* to express (without repetition of the wrapper chars):

```
var energy = _.map(fruits, function wrap(f) { return '{'+f+'}'; }).join(' ');
```

However, this is probably slower than joining by `} {`.